# How to add more items to ItemsControl after binding

Tags: c#, wpf

In my C# windows phone app, I create a binding to bind a list of string to `ItemsControl`.

```
// MyCollections is a List<string>

<ItemsControl x:Name="ContentRoot" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollections}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding }" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

It works. But My question is how can I add my own item (e.g. 'Click to add more') to this `ItemsControl` after it is binded?

Comment: add to MyCollections in code behind.

Comment: also instead of `List<string>` use `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>`. it will update the control automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two answers to this question:

1. Use an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List`, as it will notify the UI when items are added/removed from it. Then you just add your new item to the list in the view model.
2. Use a `CompositeCollection` so you can have the "additional" item without modifying the actual collection.

Normally you would do 1, but since you want a "Click to add more" type of option, `CompositeCollection` is probably the way to go.

Since you metioned windows phone (but tagged WPF) you may want to look at this post for how to write your own `CompositeCollection` object: [how to do a CompositeCollection in WP8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717846/how-to-do-a-compositecollection-in-wp8)

Comment: Thanks. I tried the ObservableCollection(). I add new item to it in  private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)(). But when I go back and forth between this page, I see more and more items being added to the list. Is there a better place to do that?

Comment: @hap497 I would add it in the view model, when you load the initial collection.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`CompositeCollection`** to add additional items in your XAML. This should work:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="myCollection">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.MyCollections,
                                                  Source={x:Reference stackPanel}}"/>
            <ContentControl Content="Click to add more"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ContentRoot"
                  ItemsSource="{StaticResource myCollection}"/>
</StackPanel>
```